# My Service is not working on Android, why?

Tags: java, android

It's code here:

```
public class MyServeice extends Service 
{
    private Timer pushTimer;
    private final int NOTEF_ID = 1234;
    NotificationManager manager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        Log.i("MyActivity", "1");
        //pushTimer = new Timer();
        manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        Log.i("MyActivity", "2");
        //pushTimer.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) 
    {
        Log.i("MyActivity", "3");
        //pushTimer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        //{
        //  @Override
        //  public void run() 
        //  {
                Notification not = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Custom notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
                PendingIntent notIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this , 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
                not.setLatestEventInfo(this,  "Title", "Text", notIntent);
                manager.notify(NOTEF_ID, not);
                manager.cancel(NOTEF_ID);
        //  }
        //}, 0L, 60L * 1000);
    }

}
```

I try to start it from my MainActivity activity class (before I thought that problem is in timer, but now I comment it).
Starting code here:

`startService(new Intent(this, MyServeice.class));`

Log from Service class is not shown, so I decided that Service is not started at all. Application doesn't crash and started normaly. Can you check my code?

Comment: Is your service registered in the manifest? Please post your manifest also.

Comment: post the code from the activity, where you are opening the service.

Comment: You can use `MyServeice.this` to refer to the outer class in the `TimerTask`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake in **MyServeice** Class

You use

```
 @Override
 public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid)
```

& in **Service** Life cycle there is no onStart(..) Method

Try this method instead of above

```
  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
```

**EDIT:**

& second One you have to declare service in Manifest File Like:

```
<manifest ... >
  ...
  <application ... >
      <service android:name=".MyServeice" />
      ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

For more Information About Service Refer this Documentation
 http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this method :

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {}
```

Here is good tutorial about services : [Click here !](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html)

Answer (score -2):

Question closed. Adding info about my service class into manifest  solved my problem.